# Haskell "persistent" model: How to correctly define cross-reference?

Tags: database, haskell, model, haskell-persistent

Imagine you have two models (**Foo** and **Bar**) and they are both have references to each other (**Foo** have **barRef** with type **BarId** and **Bar** have **fooRef** with type **FooId**). Everything goes okay:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack script --resolver=lts-9.21 --package=persistent-template -}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, QuasiQuotes, TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import Database.Persist.TH

mkPersist sqlSettings [persistLowerCase|
Foo
  barModel BarId
  fooField Int

Bar
  fooModel FooId
  barField Int
|]

main = pure ()
```

But if I wrap reference type to **Maybe** (just an example, it could **Vector** or anything else):

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack script --resolver=lts-9.21 --package=persistent-template -}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, QuasiQuotes, TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import Database.Persist.TH

mkPersist sqlSettings [persistLowerCase|
Foo
  barModel (Maybe BarId)
  fooField Int

Bar
  fooModel FooId
  barField Int
|]

main = pure ()
```

It fails with this error:

```
Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘BarId’
```

How I am supposed to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you are using for the `Bar` model isn't right. Something like this should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack script --resolver lts-12.7

{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, QuasiQuotes, TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import Database.Persist.TH

mkPersist sqlSettings [persistLowerCase|
Foo
  barModel BarId Maybe
  fooField Int

Bar
  fooModel FooId
  barField Int
|]

main = pure ()
```

See the [official docs](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/blob/master/docs/Persistent-entity-syntax.md) for reference.

Comment: I'm actually faced this issue using **Vector**, for some reason I have thought this syntax is only for **Maybe**, like just for nullable fields. But I realized now that this is general syntax for any wrapper in reverse order. So it could be even `barModel BarId Vector Maybe` for `barModel :: Maybe (Vector (BarId))`. Thanks!

Comment: @unclechu I'm not sure something like that will work out. Test that out and let us know.

Comment: I was wrong, this doesn't work like that, `Maybe` is just a special case.